# R CLMM: Reaching Iteration Limit for Random Effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, ordered-logit

I have a dataset with the characteristics of 10001 applications from a major app store. The apps have been repeatedly observed for 14 weeks. In total I have 140014 observations. (There are missings which gives me 12776 obs.) 
The depending variable (CIB) is ordered with different distances between its values. 
I want to estimate a cumulative link mixed model to find associations between the dependent and independent variables using the **ordinal** package and the **clmm** command.

```
> str(h6)
'data.frame':   12776 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ CIB         : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ NumberID    : int  2048 433 4751 5291 75 536 3262 2404 163 4735 ...
 $ logiPrice   : num  1.00e-07 1.00e-07 1.00e-07 5.99 1.00e-07 1.00e-07 1.00e-07 1.00e-07 9.90e-01 1.00e-07 ...
     $ logPrice    : num  -9.21 -9.21 1.29 -9.21 2.18 ...
 $ in_app_purch: num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ AvRating    : num  4 0 4.59 4.64 0 ...
 $ nec_PV      : num  2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 ...

> head(h6)
CIB NumberID logiPrice logPrice in_app_purch AvRating nec_PV
32   1     2048  1.00e-07 -9.21034            0 4.000000    2.2
52   1      433  1.00e-07 -9.21034            0 0.000000    2.2
55   1     4751  1.00e-07  1.29000            1 4.586207    2.2
67   1     5291  5.99e+00 -9.21034            0 4.636364    2.2
79   1       75  1.00e-07  2.18000            0 0.000000    2.2
81   1      536  1.00e-07  2.14000            0 0.000000    2.2
```

I have more variables than shown here (in total about 50), but I wanted to start with an easier model. I included a random effect, which is NumberID and represents the ID of an App. So there would be 10001 different values for this variable. To start and get some more information I used a subsample of 1400 observations. I obtained the following, using equidistant thresholds and a logit link:

```
reg2 <- clmm(formula = CIB ~ logiPrice + in_app_purch + AvRating + (1|NumberID), data = h3, link = "logit", threshold ="equidistant", nAGQ = 10)

Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the adaptive Gauss-Hermite 
quadrature approximation with 10 quadrature points 

formula: CIB ~ logiPrice + in_app_purch + AvRating + (1 | NumberID)
data:    h3

 link  threshold   nobs logLik AIC    niter      max.grad cond.H 
 logit equidistant 1253 -75.10 162.20 794(23417) 2.17e+01 8.3e+06

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 NumberID (Intercept) 2887     53.73   
Number of groups:  NumberID 96 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
logiPrice    -0.753321   4.276231  -0.176     0.86    
in_app_purch 34.816010   2.838936  12.264   <2e-16 ***
AvRating      0.353238   0.001516 232.993   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value
threshold.1 33.981616   0.001517   22396
spacing     42.236683   0.001518   27828
(131 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

nAGq=10 supposed to yield higher precision. The conditional number of the Hessian is very high. I read it supposed to be below 1e^04. I also tried a probit link, the same issue occurs. If I repeat the analysis with flexible thresholds, I get 8 warnings, all of them saying (with different values for the iterations):

```
 In update.uC(rho) :
  iteration limit reached when updating the random effects
  at iteration 527
```

Using clm to calculate the same simple model without the random effect, I get:

```
reg1 <- clm(formula = CIB ~ logiPrice + in_app_purch + AvRating, data = h3, link = "logit", threshold ="equidistant")

summary(reg1)
formula: CIB ~ logiPrice + in_app_purch + AvRating
data:    h3

 link  threshold   nobs logLik  AIC     niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit equidistant 1253 -754.82 1519.63 6(0)  9.37e-12 4.1e+02

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
logiPrice    -0.03721    0.03246  -1.147    0.252    
in_app_purch  3.27102    0.34109   9.590  < 2e-16 ***
AvRating      0.35178    0.04993   7.045 1.86e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value
threshold.1   2.6252     0.2059   12.75
spacing       1.8169     0.1163   15.62
(131 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Here the conditional number of the Hessian is lower. When I extend my data set to 14000 and include the random effect again (and flexible TH), I get:

```
reg3 <- clmm(formula = CIB ~ logiPrice + in_app_purch + AvRating + (1|NumberID), data = h3, link = "logit", threshold ="flexible", nAGQ = 10)
```

I get 50 warnings all of the kind

```
50: In update.uC(rho) : iteration limit reached when updating the random effects
  at iteration 17901
```

The results seem o.k.

```
summary(reg3)
    Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the adaptive Gauss-Hermite 
    quadrature approximation with 10 quadrature points 

formula: CIB ~ logiPrice + in_app_purch + AvRating + (1 | NumberID)
data:    h3

 link  threshold nobs  logLik   AIC     niter      max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  13107 -1351.84 2719.67 781(21471) 4.31e+06 1.1e+00

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 NumberID (Intercept) 161.6    12.71   
Number of groups:  NumberID 973 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
logiPrice    -6.724e-01  3.575e-06 -188069   <2e-16 ***
in_app_purch  1.493e+01  3.575e-06 4174492   <2e-16 ***
AvRating     -2.291e+00  3.575e-06 -640728   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2 -3.222e+00  3.575e-06 -901220
2|3  1.008e+01  3.575e-06 2819331
3|4  2.404e+01  3.575e-06 6724464
4|5  3.207e+01  3.575e-06 8968751
(540 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Even though the cond. H. seems ok, there seems to be a problem with the random effects term. The calculation of the full sample with the same specification takes a very long time (I am not sure if it converges at all). I am not sure if it is because of the amount of data or an issue with the random effects term. My questions are:

- Can I trust the results?
- Do I make some mistake when I include the random effect for the applications (class of the RA variable etc.)?
- Is there something I could do to improve the fitting?
- Is the only way to improve it by adding explanatory variables?

EDIT: I run a Model with an Intercept and a random term and it does not do well. Is there just not enough variation between the individuals to identify an effect? A full specified model without the random effect converges in 12 seconds using clm.

Comment: I found a helpful question answered by Rune, the author of clmm. It does not solve my problem, but may help others: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q1/015330.html